# Is there a JavaScript function to link ranges (top range 0----100 bottom range 55%----24%) known top input, want bottom value output

Tags: javascript, formula, calc

The following image will help explain what I am trying to achieve...
[image]

The top line (A) is a given calculated JavaScript value, lets call this the input.
The bottom line (B) is the output, so whatever input to (A) is given (will always be within the range) if a line (like the green one shown) were to be drawn I need the value of the output.

I have tried to search for phrases like "linked range", "parallel linked values" and similar but I think half of my problem is not knowing what this kind of calulation is called.

Usually I would be able to show what I have tried but on this one I really dont have a clue where to start.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: SO you want the value, not the actual picture? It is a basic math equation.

Comment: @epascarello yes the value is what I need, the picture is just to show better what I mean

Comment: So calculate what the percentage of the value that in in the range A. And then use that 
 percentage to figure out what the number would be in the second range. `A[value] / ( A[max] - A[min] )`

Comment: @epascarello the real values for (A) are min=2500 max=3000000 (not the 0-100 as shown) and i'd like to be able to change the min and max percentage values for (B).

I could achieve this by actually using 2 range sliders (hidden) one above the other and after input have JavaScript read the actual position of A on the track (not the value) and then have it put (B) in the same place, then read the value of (B) but this seems far from the correct approach to the problem given the range sliders are not actaully needed as these are back end calulations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So get the percentage in A

`percentage = A[value] / ( A[max] - A[min] )`

Use that to figure out the value in second

`result = B[max] - percentage * (B[max] - B[min])`

so basic JavaScript

```js
var aMin = 0;
var aMax = 500;
var bMin = 24;
var bMax = 55;

var aValue = 100;

var percentage = aValue / ( aMax - aMin );
var result = bMax - percentage * (bMax - bMin);
console.log(result + "%");
```

Comment: epascarello: Perfect, many thanks, do you know is there a name for this type of calculation?